# How can I get an hstore query that searches multiple terms to use indexes?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a query that is underperforming, data is an `hstore` column:

`SELECT "vouchers".* FROM "vouchers"  WHERE "vouchers"."type" IN ('VoucherType') AND ((data -> 'giver_id')::integer = 1) AND ((data -> 'recipient_email') is NULL)`

I've tried adding the following indexes:

`CREATE INDEX free_boxes_recipient ON vouchers USING gin ((data->'recipient_email')) WHERE ((data->'recipient_email') IS NULL);`

`CREATE INDEX voucher_type_giver ON vouchers USING gin ((data->'giver_id')::int)`

As well as an overall index: `CREATE INDEX voucher_type_data ON vouchers USING gin (data)`

Here's the current query plan:

```
Seq Scan on vouchers  (cost=0.00..15158.70 rows=5 width=125) (actual time=122.818..122.818 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: (((data -> 'recipient_email'::text) IS NULL) AND ((type)::text = 'VoucherType'::text) AND (((data -> 'giver_id'::text))::integer = 1))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 335148
Planning time: 0.196 ms
Execution time: 122.860 ms
```

How can I index this hstore column to get it down to a more reasonable query?

Comment: `((data->'recipient_email') IS NULL` -- is this the same as `NOT (data ? 'recipient_email')` in your context? Does substitution improve anything?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I don't see a GIN index on keys here, so I'm rushing at conclusions. Still, I don't think GIN is particularly useful here, given that you're indexing **a string**. Try a plain old B-tree instead?

Comment: "Rows removed by filter" is about 330k. How many rows are in your table? If that's only 1% of your table, that makes a big difference. ;) Also... 0.12 seconds is under performing? How many times per second is this query getting run? +1 nonetheless, though. Good question (at least in my opinion).

Comment: 335k rows total in the table :) -- also yeah, I believe 0.12s is underperforming, it does get run a lot, that query is consuming the most time across our rather large and heavily trafficked application.

Comment: Ah, so you already profiled it. =) Good info to include up front to avoid people like me asking. ;) A *lot* of users fail to think that far ahead when asking performance questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

> hstore has GiST and GIN index support for the @>, ?, ?& and ?| operators.

You are searching for an integer value so you can use simple btree index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON vouchers (((data->'giver_id')::int));

EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT * 
FROM vouchers
WHERE vtype IN ('VoucherType') 
AND (data -> 'giver_id')::integer = 1 
AND (data -> 'recipient_email') is NULL;

                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on vouchers  (cost=4.66..82.19 rows=1 width=34) (actual time=0.750..0.858 rows=95 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((data -> 'giver_id'::text))::integer = 1)
   Filter: (((data -> 'recipient_email'::text) IS NULL) AND (vtype = 'VoucherType'::text))
   Heap Blocks: exact=62
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vouchers_int4_idx  (cost=0.00..4.66 rows=50 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=95 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (((data -> 'giver_id'::text))::integer = 1)
 Planning time: 2.115 ms
 Execution time: 0.896 ms
(8 rows)
```